# How to copy exact number of characters c-string

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I am having some difficulty copying over some characters into a `c-string` array.

Basically, if the size of the array is defined as 25, and the user inputs 25 characters, it stores the 25 characters and deletes the contents in the other char arrays, as it is a overflow.

Is there a way of copying exactly 25 characters into an array, as I am aware that you need to account for the `\0` null terminating character.

This is my header file and code,

```
  #define FIRSTNAME 25
  #define SURNAME 128
  #define ADDRESS 128
  #define INFORMATION 128

class Customers
{
private:
    char firstName[FIRSTNAME];
    char surname[SURNAME];
    char address[ADDRESS];
    char information[INFORMATION];


public:
    Customers();

    void setFirstName(char *firstName);
    void setSurname(char *surname);
    void setAddress(char *address);
    void setInformation(char *information);

    const char* getFirstName() const {return firstName;};
    const char* getSurname() const {return surname;};
    const char* getAddress() const {return address;};
    const char* getInformation() const {return information;};

    ~Customers();

};
```

Code:

```
void Customers::setFirstName(char *firstName)
{
    strncpy(this->firstName, firstName, FIRSTNAME);
    this->firstName[FIRSTNAME - 1] = '\0';
}

void Customers::setSurname(char *surname)
{
    strncpy(this->surname, surname, SURNAME);
    this->surname[SURNAME - 1] = '\0';
}

void Customers::setAddress(char *address)
{
    strncpy(this->address, address, ADDRESS);
    this->address[ADDRESS - 1] = '\0';
}

void Customers::setInformation(char *information)
{
    strncpy(this->information, information, INFORMATION);
    this->information[INFORMATION - 1] = '\0';
}
```

This code above works fine but it copies the `maximum size - 1` character over.

I tried the following code below to copy over characters that are the maximum size, but it erases what is in the other variables...

```
void Customers::setFirstName(char *firstName)
{
    strcpy(this->firstName, firstName); // IF *firstName is 25 characters, it stores 25 characters and erases what is in the surname variable
}

void Customers::setSurname(char *surname)
{
    strcpy(this->surname, surname); // IF *surname is 128 characters, it stores 128 characters and erases what is in the address variable
}

void Customers::setAddress(char *address)
{
    strcpy(this->address, address); // IF *address is 128 characters, it stores 128 characters and erases what is in the information variable
}

void Customers::setInformation(char *information)
{
    strcpy(this->information, information);
}
```

How do I copy over all characters, even if it is the maximum size? For example, if surname was actually 128 characters long, I don't want it to erase anything in the `address` variable. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Why are you using C-string instead of `std::string`?

Comment: And that's why I hate C and C++ tag together.

Answer (score 1):

If i have understood your question correctly, what you need is [`strncpy()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy) or [memcpy()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy), which will copy exactly `n` bytes.

Here, you need to be careful while giving the value of `n`. If `n` is equal to the size of the supplied target buffer and there  is no null byte among the first n bytes of the source, there will be no space left for the terminating null.

So, IMO, if you want to copy exactly `n` bytes then define the array to be of size `n+1`, copy exactly `n` bytes and and put a '\0' at `n`th variable [Considering index starts from `0`].

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. But in that case must not have to use the character array as a string, i.e, you must not apply any string operation on it (as it is not `\0` terminated and will invoke undefined behavior).

To copy that array, you can use a loop or standard library function [`memcpy`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) or [`memmove`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memmove.3.html).

Comment: Do you know `memcpy`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but don't ever use any `str*` function on the resulting array, it would not be a string without the terminating `'\0'` byte. You can't treat them as strings, it's still useful though if you want to store them in a file, just specify the length of the array when copying their contents using `sizeof` operator for instance. For example to write them to `stdout` you can

```
fwrite(array, 1, sizeof(array), stdout);
```

and so on.

Also, I would suggest the [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html) function since it copies exactly the number of bytes you need for example

```
strncpy(this->information, information, INFORMATION);
```

would be

```
memcpy(this->information, information, INFORMATION);
```

with `memcpy` no terminating `'\0'` will be added, so I thing that is what you need.